# How to use HTMLUnit with Selenium 2.45.0 on Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't use HTMLUnit, I try that:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
```

but it returns that:
http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2015/03/01/15030112220341529.png

And Python2 returns:
http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2015/03/01/150301122202928469.png

I installed Selenium 2.45.0 like this for Python3:

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```

And like this for Python2:

```
pip2 install -U selenium
```

Thanks for any help !

PS: I used screenshots, because the error was too long to be displayed.